# alternating methods

Tags: java, methods

I have a recursive function that calls a method inside it. I want to be able to call my other sorting methods within the same testing method. I have 4 other methods (`mergeSort` for example). How would I go about cycling through the method calls so that the tester runs through the all the sorting tests (of all different sized arrays) on one method (`selectionSort`) then moves to the next method (`mergeSort`) and proceeds to test it starting from `size = 100` again and continuing on from there?

```
public void testSorts(){

    for(int size = 100; size<=100000; size = size*10){
        String[] data;
        long start;
        long time;

        UI.println("\n\n======Selection Sort=======\n");

        data = createArray(size);
        //printData(data);
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        selectionSort(data);
        //             insertionSort(data);
        //             bubbleSort(data);
        //             mergeSort(data);
        //             quickSort(data);
        //             quickSort2(data);
        time =  System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

        UI.printf("Number of items:  %,d\n", data.length);
        UI.printf("Sorted correcetly: %b\n", testSorted(data));
        UI.printf("Time taken:       %.2f s\n", time/1000.0);

        UI.println("\n=======DONE=========\n");

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `interface`s? IMO they are the right way to approach this issue.

Comment: Interfaces or function pointers, the choice is yours

Comment: @Minion91 Java doesn't have function pointers. Although AFAIK Java 8 will have closures.

Comment: @S.L.Barth sorry, to fast for my own wits

Answer (score 1):

In short: Use strategy pattern.

Create interface `Sorter` with method `sort`.

Create class for each sorting method.

create `Sorter[]` and rotate through it.

Answer (score 0):

Create an *interface* `SortingAlgorithm`, which will have a `sort(String[])` method, and will be implemented by different classes - one for each algorithm.

Now, use a method that accepts as an argument a `SortingAlgorithm` and invokes `algorith.sort(data)`.

(For example, you can have `public void testSorts(SortingAlgorithm algorithm)` method which will invoke a single algorithm, the one that was passed as an argument).

The relevant algorithm will be invoked.